Exception thrown when JAVA calls libgandiva_jni.so on ARM (but successfully on x86 platform)
We have encountered a wierd issue about libgandiva_jni.so. Same Java program calls Arrow 9.0.0's libgandiva_jni.so (compiled successfully) with different results on ARM and x86 platform. On ARM platform, it throwed out an exception as below,
undefined symbol: _ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPSs

Then we traced this problem, and found it was blocked in the method:
llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::getPermanentLibrary(char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)

Furthermore, we have found this method lies in "libLLVMSupport.a", but we are sure this libLLVMSupport.a file has been linked in shared lib. Below is the command we used:
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC  -Wno-noexcept-type  -fdiagnostics-color=always -O3 -DNDEBUG \
-Wall -fno-semantic-interposition -march=armv8-a  -O3 -DNDEBUG \
-Wl,--version-script=/path/to/arrow-9.0.0/cpp/src/gandiva/jni/symbols.map \
-shared -Wl,-soname,libgandiva_jni.so.900 -o \
../../../release/libgandiva_jni.so.900.0.0 \
CMakeFiles/gandiva_jni_objlib.dir/config_builder.cc.o \
CMakeFiles/gandiva_jni_objlib.dir/config_holder.cc.o \
CMakeFiles/gandiva_jni_objlib.dir/expression_registry_helper.cc.o \
CMakeFiles/gandiva_jni_objlib.dir/jni_common.cc.o \
CMakeFiles/gandiva_jni_objlib.dir/Types.pb.cc.o \
../../../protobuf_ep-install/lib/libprotobuf.a ../../../release/libgandiva.a \
../../../release/libarrow.a ../../../protobuf_ep-install/lib/libprotobuf.a \
../../../brotli_ep/src/brotli_ep-install/lib/libbrotlienc-static.a \
../../../brotli_ep/src/brotli_ep-install/lib/libbrotlidec-static.a \
../../../brotli_ep/src/brotli_ep-install/lib/libbrotlicommon-static.a \
../../../bzip2_ep-install/lib/libbz2.a \
../../../lz4_ep-prefix/src/lz4_ep/lib/liblz4.a \
../../../snappy_ep/src/snappy_ep-install/lib/libsnappy.a \
../../../zstd_ep-install/lib64/libzstd.a ../../../orc_ep-install/lib/liborc.a \
../../../jemalloc_ep-prefix/src/jemalloc_ep/dist//lib/libjemalloc_pic.a \
-pthread /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMMCJIT.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMExecutionEngine.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMOrcTargetProcess.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMOrcShared.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMipo.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMFrontendOpenMP.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMIRReader.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAsmParser.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMVectorize.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMInstrumentation.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMLinker.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAArch64CodeGen.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAsmPrinter.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMDebugInfoMSF.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMGlobalISel.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMSelectionDAG.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMCodeGen.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMTarget.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMBitWriter.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMScalarOpts.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAggressiveInstCombine.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMInstCombine.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMTransformUtils.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAnalysis.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMProfileData.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMDebugInfoDWARF.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMObject.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMBitReader.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMTextAPI.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMCFGuard.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMCore.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMRemarks.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMBitstreamReader.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAArch64AsmParser.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMMCParser.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAArch64Disassembler.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAArch64Desc.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMMCDisassembler.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAArch64Info.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMMC.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMBinaryFormat.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMDebugInfoCodeView.a \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMAArch64Utils.a /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMSupport.a \
/usr/lib64/libz.so -lrt -ldl -lpthread -lm /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so \
/usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMDemangle.a /usr/lib64/libssl.so \
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so ../../../re2_ep-install/lib/libre2.a \
../../../utf8proc_ep-install/lib/libutf8proc.a

Environment details:
OS: CentOS v7.6
Tools: GCC 8.3.1, LLVM 14
By the way, the command we used for Arrow 9 compilation on ARM platform is as follows,
cmake .. -DARROW_GANDIVA_JAVA=ON -DARROW_GANDIVA=ON  -DARROW_WITH_RE2=ON -DARROW_WITH_UTF8PROC=ON

On arrow 16.1 (libgandiva_jni.so is NOT compiled manually, but copied from https://repository.apache.org/#nexus-search;quick~arrow-gandiva) , we did the same thing, but it throwed out a different error:
GandivaException: Failed to make LLVM module due to Could not create LLJIT instance: Symbols not found: [ llvm_orc_registerEHFrameSectionWrapper ]

Hope this helpful. If I missed anything, please let me know.
We did this w/ Arrow 9 and Arrow 16, get different errors.

So what does nm --undefined-only --dynamic ../../../release/libgandiva_jni.so.900.0.0 produce? And does nm /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMSupport.a contain the missing symbol? Edit your question with the output.

@Botje  We did run
1, 'nm --undefined-only --dynamic release/libgandiva_jni.so.900.0.0 |grep ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPSs U _ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPSs'
2. [code block] nm /usr/local/llvm/lib/libLLVMSupport.a |grep _ZN4llvm3sys14DynamicLibrary19getPermanentLibraryEPKcPSs
But nothing returned.

Then libLLVMSupport.a does not define that symbol, despite your initial analysis

@Botje, so what we need to do? please advise. Thanks!

Find the library where that symbol is defined OR figure out why it is not in the place you expect it to be.
